# vprintf not consuming item from va_list

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a variation of printf where the item being printed and the format being printed are adjacent parameters in the call like...

```
print(2, "%s", "hello", "%.5u", 25);
```

I have studied up on var args and came up with....

```
void print(int count, ...)
{
    va_list varg;
    va_start(varg, count);

    while(count-- > 0)
    { 
      char* format = va_arg(varg, char*);
      vprintf(format, varg);
    }               

    va_end(varg);
}
```

It appears that vprintf is not consuming the item it is using from the stack. My output is

hellohello

I believe this is being expanded out too

```
printf("%s", "hello);
printf("hello");
```

So what am I doing wrong that vprintf isn't consuming the "hello" from the arg list?

Update: per the comment below

```
void print(int count, ...)
{
    va_list varg;
    va_start(varg, count);

    while(count-- > 0)
    { 
      char* format = va_arg(varg, char*);
      void* arg    = va_arg(varg, void*);
      printf(format, arg);
    }               

    va_end(varg);
}
```

This seems to get the job done.

Comment: I wouldn't count on that working on all systems, since the type provided to va_arg must be the actual type of the argument. Quoting the standard: "If there is no actual next argument, or if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined,". Two exceptions are provided: void* and char* are interchangeable; and unsigned and signed types are interchangeable if the value is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The va_list is nothing but an address (in typical implementations). It is passed by value to the function, so the original in the calling function is unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is undefined behavior. In the C99 standard, section 7.15 paragraph 3, it says:

> The type declared is `va_list` which is an object type suitable for
>   holding information needed by the macros `va_start`, `va_arg`,
>   `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is
>   desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally
>   referred to as `ap` in this subclause) having type `va_list`. **The
>   object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function; if that
>   function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the value of
>   `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to
>   the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.**

Here, you're passing the `va_list` variable `varg` to the function `vprintf`, which calls `va_arg` on it internally. Thus, after it returns, you are not allowed to use `varg` anymore. You are required to call `va_end` on it before doing anything else with it. Instead, you are using it in the next iteration of the loop without first calling `va_end`. So you are running into undefined behavior.

Comment: Further to this; `va_copy` can be used if you want to process a list twice. Although what OP is trying is probably impossible to do portably.